# Why are many programmers moving their code to github?

Tags: open-source, development-process, project-hosting

For the past 6 months or more, I've been seeing many codes hosted at sourceforge.net as well as other hosting sites "Move to GitHub". A mere Google Search with the phrase "Moved to Github" returns several results containing the text moved to github. This is very confusing for me, and I'm wondering, why exactly are people moving? Does it mean that GitHub is better or is there some special advantage I'm not seeing?

Comment: I would also add that no site makes it easier to interact with code right away than github. Most sites hide the source-code behind several menus. Github also includes links to just about any other task you could right there on the project home without all the junk everywhere (looking at you *sourceforge*).

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, so I went and signed up, and pretty soon I was sold, too. I switched all of my projects over, and got all my clients on board as well.

Comment: because github is a nice place and git is better than cvs?

Comment: I agree with @Xeoncross. As another example, with bitbucket, the default active tab is "overview" which presents you with metadata and a bunch of other noise. The "source" tab is the 4th over and doesn't stand out at all. What a usability nightmare. I'd be surprised if the people behind bitbucket actually enjoy using bitbucket.

Comment: Also note that github is one of the most popular places (together with topcoder) that technical recruiters are checking.

Comment: SourceForge started adding adware to its devs' Windows binary releases; one of SF's distribution servers in Korea was compromised.

Comment: Laucnpad is an even worse offender in hiding the source.  What stands out is some "Series and milestones" -> trunk -> "Code for this series:
The following branch has been registered as the mainline branch for this release series: lp:~USER/PROJ/trunk" -> yet another metadata page for trunk?  where is the code?  oh yes, ->"Browse the code"...   Actually now I finally noticed there was "Browse the code" right on the first page.  But all these alike-but-subtly-different metadata pages are bewildering.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This is a symptom of a wider migration towards [**distributed** version control systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).

Some websites which traditionally hosted non distributed VCS (eg Codeplex & SourceForge) were a little slow in adding support for DVCS (eg Git or Mercurial). So, people who wanted to use DVCS for their project were forced to migrate their projects over to the providers which supported them (eg Github or BitBucket). Github was one of the first to offer DVCS support and so naturally a lot of people migrated their code there in order to take advantage of it.

Those other websites are only now starting to catch up to DVCS (Codeplex for example now supports Mercurial & Git), but they are still a way behind in terms of features such as forking and submitting pull requests. To really take advantage of DVCS Github and Bitbucket are still the best options.

Comment: Hmm, looks great. Just read up DVCS through the link you provided, but there're some statements I don't understand. I've not really been using code hosting, except for a few write on my local PC and upload. All I can grab is that DVCS seems to provide a very easy way for multiple people to work on a project independently and still update synchronously...?

Comment: Also note that GitHub's feature set rapidly became far more attractive than any other DVCS hoster offered (including self-hosting). So, part of the answer is that GitHub is sexy. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ...except for free private hosting, which BitBucket had been offering for ages.

Comment: Other websites offer DVCS. In the particular case of SourceForge, I simply think the reason is that the website is utterly horrible, never mind the supported version control systems.

Comment: @Den Yea, I really don't know why BitBucket isn't more popular. It has private hosting and let's you choose between Git or Mercurial (which I like Mercurial a lot more)

Comment: @Earlz BitBucket only supported Mercurial for a while, and it wasn't quite as nice as GitHub until recently (now, I'd argue that it's better, but historically, not really). EDIT: To be more specific, GitHub was founded in 2008 and supported git immediately. BitBucket was founded in 2010 and only added git support near the end of 2011.

Comment: Huh, yeah, I didn't know BitBucket offered git. It was Hg-only for the longest time. Hmm. Might need to take a look since I don't know if I like paying for Github.

Comment: @Kyle Definitely check out BitBucket, it's feature set might feel a bit barebones compared to GitHub, but I always felt it provides exactly what I need, and the "features" it's lacking are more distractions than anything useful. Oh, and the one time I reported a bug, I got a response in less than an hour,  that's always nice (and the bug was fixed couple of days later).

Comment: Github and Bitbucket operate on two different business models.  Github offers almost its' full feature set for free and makes you pay for private repos (bar the free Bronze plans it [gives to anyone with a .edu email address](http://github.com/edu]). Bitbucket offers both public and private hosting but charges you for the [hopefully] productivity-increasing extras.  If you don't have a reason to hide you code, Github seems like the more logical model. I do think Bitbucket is coming around though -- I certainly like Sourcetree better than Github's native git GUI (not that I really use either)..

Comment: Neither SF or BB seem to value usability which to me means they don't value their user's time or they are too lazy to be bothered with it. Either is a turn-off for me and I suspect, to most of the open-source world at large. The fact that Github doesn't need to match Bitbucket's free private repo offer should be quite telling of the situation. Bitbucket gives away free private repos; but that is a band-aid...it doesn't make up for the usability issues and also being extremely late to the party.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the reason people are avoiding SourceForge now not only because of their website, but also because of their sometime overly strict project approval. I submitted a project for a small hobby OS and got rejected... At the time, Github was still new and experimental, so I went with google code. Personally, I think all of the traditional sites are beat out by Bitbucket's user interface and options. Personally, I like Bitbucket's site more than Github even

Comment: What about Gitlab compared to Github and BitBucket, right now?

Answer (score 45):

Project hosting is infrastructure. Infrastructure exhibits network effects, which means that infrastructure gets more useful the more people are connected to it. (In particular, the usefulness is O(number_of_connections), which means that for any individual member it is O(total_members) and for the whole system it is O(total_members^2)). This, in turn, leads to an effect called natural monopoly, which means that it is natural for such a system that only one competitor will survive, since the usefulness is maximized when everybody uses the same system.

So, it makes sense to join the market leader, which is GitHub. There are more repositories, more users, more branches, more revisions, more *everything* on GitHub than on SourceForge, Google Code and CodePlex *combined*.

The interesting question is, of course, if network effects mean that the market leader automatically obtains a natural monopoly, how was GitHub able to break SourceForge's?

And the answer is, by being *so* disruptive that the pain of joining a much smaller infrastructure was worth it for the early adopters:

- GitHub was the first to offer Git hosting with a feature set comparable to that of SourceForge (or at least that part of SourceForge that most people used)
- GitHub was cool, from a UI standpoint: slick, modern Web UI
- GitHub was cool, technology-wise: Ruby on Rails, Sinatra, Erlang, node.js
- GitHub was Web 2.0, with its focus on Social Coding, and Users over Projects

Comment: +1 for the network effects explanation. But I really think SourceForge was much bigger than Github before the sudden rampant migrations... and you almost sound like a Github employee...

Comment: Additionally, consider the creation of the  [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) client - for the first time, as a Windows developer, I don't feel like a second-class citizen when it comes to using Git for source control, and GitHub is responsible for that.

Answer (score 25):

I think one of the reasons is different audience: sourceforge is primarily for hosting *applications*, probably the most prominent feature of a project page is a link to the compiled executable (or some other download). In other words, it's targeted at *users*, not developers.

On the other hand, github is primarily for hosting *source code*, the most prominent feature of the project page is directory listing of the `master` branch. It's targeted at *developers* (either wanting to modify or use code from a project), not users.

I think this is one of the reasons why developer-targeted tools and libraries are moving to github.

Answer (score 15):

Sourceforge [also offers Git](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git), but Github just does it better (for now).

- Their pull request system works nicely (much better than Gitorious for instance)
- Their recently-upgraded notification is very convenient.
- They show the code right away

Their **killer feature**, in my opinion, is the "Network graph":

[image]

Difference with `gitk`: it also shows you what is going on in other people's branches (without having to pull their branches), which is very important when collaborating.

Comment: +1 We all know that in the end, graphs are all that matter.

Comment: It's also fantastic for finding the most maintained branch. I recently had to find which fork of a certain repository was actually maintained (non-trivial because the more up-to-date forks hadn't yet floated to the top of a google search).

Comment: also, it seems github can show clone statistics, while I cannot find a single way to do that on sourceforge :(

Answer (score 11):

GitHub is simple, easy-to-use, easy to get started with, powerful and looks great and is Web 2.0-ish.

I use GitHub, and I find it remarkably easier to use than SourceForge, which had its power hidden behind a series of menus and required fairly elaborate operations to get anything set up. And I'm a programmer.

In addition, I think there is one more powerful feature: whether its an individual wanting to publish their first open-source project somewhere, or teams that want to collaborate on a commercial (private) project, GitHub "scales" perfectly well for almost all use cases.

End of the day, I think its about human psychology. Is the product easy to use, easy to start using, inexpensive (or free) ... does it look good and is it something I would recommend to my friends? For GitHub, I would answer yes to all those questions.

Comment: With Google code, I can star issues, which lets the devs know which issues are important to the community and helps me keep track of progress. Github only seems to have anonymous following, which can lead to comment spam (+1, me too, etc). This is significant for popular projects with limited resources.

Answer (score 5):

You've also got to take into account some pretty smashing features offered by github that I've yet to see mentioned.

- github pages with github flavored markdown
- github mobile app
- github eclipse plugin
- github for mac
- [github jobs](http://jobs.github.com/)
- github for windows
- github ticketing/bug tracking system
- github developer api which allows for seamless third party
  integration
- frequent UI updates/enhancements (you can literally see the changes
  from one day to the next i.e. [search text box now dynamically expands
  on focus](https://github.com/blog/1264-introducing-the-command-bar), watch became the new star button, etc.)
- github [gists](https://gist.github.com/gists) (good
  for utility scripts, short code snippets, etc.)
- seamless github integration via [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub)

Other sites may have these features but I'm pretty sure no site out there has them all.

These guys are practically everywhere...slowly dispersing their technical goodies throughout the web and desktop alike. They're only [getting bigger and better](http://go.bloomberg.com/tech-deals/2012-07-09-github-takes-100m-in-largest-investment-by-andreessen-horowitz/) as we speak and they hire the finest of engineers (they even managed to steal Phil Haack from Microsoft...go figure).

Answer (score 4):

One additional reason that may be drawing additional developers to GitHub is that developer tools are starting to embrace git, and platforms like Eclipse now have Git support built in out of the box (applies to the packages for Java, C++ Developers, etc), making it take less steps to get your project uploaded to GitHub.

Comment: Another IDE that added Git support is Visual Studio, in version 2013 and later.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850437.aspx for details

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, the most important thing of Git for myself when I see it:
1. Network Graph or Should I call the History(also commenting)
2. Branch and Pull Request
3. It's more powerful, really, I would say it's so feels like I have a secretary holding all my work, and I can told that sec to wrote down anything for me, the change, everything!
4. It's easy to rollback

Just it. Feels sexy using it

Comment: err, why I got below?

Comment: While I think that you had good intentions in answering the question, I don't think that your answer adds much to the answer as the OP was asking for.  It sounds like your answer to "Why are programmers moving their code to github?" is "because I like it".  Other answers here are probably better and that's why someone downvoted.